# Highcharts 'Reset Zoom' after calling setExtremes

Tags: highcharts

I am using setExtremes to zoom in on detail in a chart, as well as allowing the user to zoom 'x,y' by selecting in the chart. When the user zooms, they get a 'reset zoom' button, however when I call setExtremes, I don't.

Is there a way for me to force the 'reset zoom' button to appear programatically ?

UPDATE:

calling

```
if( !chart.resetZoomButton ) {
    chart.showResetZoom();
}
```

inside the afterSetExtremes event handler makes the button appear, but clicking it doesn't do anything.

UPDATE:

Rather than calling setExtremes, I've changed to calling

chart.xaxis[0].zoom(minx, maxx);
   chart.yaxis[0].zoom(miny, maxy);
   chart.redraw();

This has the same affect as the user zoomin in by selecting on the chart.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just had a look around the HighCharts source code, it looks like this may work out for you:

```
chart.showResetZoom();
```

Also, in order for the button to work correctly, you should use axis.zoom instead of setting the extremes:

```
axis.zoom(newMin,newMax);
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I called this inside the afterSetExtremes event handler for the x and y axis. The button now stays on the chart, but clicking it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried using axis.zoom() instead of setExtremes? It's called like axis.zoom(newMin,newMax); Perhaps the triggering of the zoom event from that function will make the button function correctly. Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on axis.zoom(). I'll give that a try.

Comment: I don't see the axis.zoom() method in the API documentation, am I missing something? What is the difference between that and setExtremes()?

Comment: Don't quite know the difference, I just know it works. ``.zoom`` is not in the documentation, it's just in the source code.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `showResetZoom`, but **you have to check if the reset button is already visible, otherwise it won't desapear**.

```
if( !chart.resetZoomButton ) {
    chart.showResetZoom();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach works well:

```
if (!$('.highcharts-button').length) {
    chart.showResetZoom();
}
```

This is assuming that the only button that might show is the "Reset Zoom" button. If it is already there, don't show another.

If you don't do this check, a new button is added each time you call `showResetZoom()`. Clicking the visible (most recent) button resets the zoom and removes the button but the older buttons are still visible and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setExtremes you can also set min and max to null to reset:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null)
```