# How dynamically set the zoom level on highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

I want to be able to dynamically set the zoom level for a highcharts scatter graph (in order to persist the zoom level). Currently the documentation suggests using the [setExtremes event method](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.setExtremes). However the issue is that this doesn't allow the chart to be reset to the original extremes. I've seen in other answers for this problem that there was a [axis zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550510/highcharts-reset-zoom-after-calling-setextremes) function however I can't seem to find this in the documentation or be able to call it from the code. Any help/ guidance with this would be much appreciated as relatively new to the highcharts library.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `setExtremes` event callback function, but `setExtremes` method:

```
document.getElementById('zoomX').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(2, 5);
});

document.getElementById('zoomY').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(4, 14);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0oLhr176/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Thank you for getting back so quickly! Unfortunately, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. The solution you gave sets the extreme how I'd expect however it doesn't allow for the extremes to be set back/ reset. For example, usually with a highchart you can select area on the graph to zoom in and you'd get a default reset zoom. However, when you use the setExtremes method the charts extremes are sort of hard set so it no longer knows about the original values. Hopefully I've explained that a bit better?

Comment: Hi @Eskimo, Thanks for the description, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uhsdnofb/

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion but I'm looking for a highcharts based solution rather than creating separate buttons & logic etc - if it exists ofc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550510/highcharts-reset-zoom-after-calling-setextremes and https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1594 these attached posts are essentially what I'm looking for here. A Highcharts method that will allow custom zooming (whilst still retaining the original extremes) without ideally having to write custom html & logic.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you would like to use `mapNavigation` from maps, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y0x1de8u/ ?

Comment: Thanks again but this still isn't quite what I'm looking for- Using a mapNavigation doesn't really solve the issue that Highcharts doesn't have a programmatic zoom function as mentioned in previous posts. For now I will assume this type of functionality just doesn't exist on highcharts as I have read through multiple stackoverflow and highcharts support posts of people requesting somewhat similar functionality.

Comment: Hi @Eskimo, There is also selection zoom: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zoomType If you could somehow visualize your idea, maybe we can find a solution.

Comment: Please see the small attached fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Eskimo/jtew2faL/31/ essentially when we zoom/ resize the extremes using the actual chart (click & drag) the chart behaves normally with a reset zoom button appearing. However when we set the zoom/ extremes using the setExtremes method the chart is no longer aware of the original values and hence does show the reset zoom button. I'm looking for a method/ solution (if possible) that allows me to manually set the extreme (so that I can persist the zoom level) but have the chart aware so the auto reset button can appear correctly

Comment: So to sum up you want to show the same working 'Reset zoom' button after click on the manually added 'Zoom' button?

Comment: So not necessarily using a button but the same working 'Reset zoom' button after I've manually used the setExtremes function in general.

Comment: Ok, but please see that if you call `chart.showResetZoom`, the button is shown and it is working, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v13f8ozd/